# Apple App-store says "The variant for one or more device types exceeds the 200 MB download size limit" for universal build

Tags: ios, app-store

The Apple App-store Connect gives the warning "The variant for one or more device types exceeds the 200 MB download size limit" for the universal build of my app. This is true, my universal build in 800+MB, but I use thinning so none of my variants exceed 128MB. so:

1. Is the universal build ever actually used if you have thinning in use?
2. Can I ignore this warning

Comment: Hi, perhaps compression would be useful?

Comment: @IronMan All my variants are well safe of the limit. The question is "is the warning valid?"